# Is it possible to refresh chrome without having inspected HTML collapse?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Every time I make a change and refresh the page I all the HTML in the dev tools view collapses and I end up loosing my place. Is it possible to stop this from happening?

Comment: A temporary fix is to select a different tab form the developer menu before refreshing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug that has returned. It should keep the currently selected node expanded upon refresh. I have added a comment to an [existing bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=93638), which needs to be re-opened. In the meantime, you can expand all nodes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> (Mac).

### Update (Sep 2 2016):

A new issue was re-opened for this and the progress can be followed [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=635981).

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was going crazy cuz I was sure it didn't used to do this, and my friend confirmed that it happened with him to and he thought It was always like this.

I just made an account and added a comment, will I get notified of any updates now? I couldn't find a "watch" feature.

Comment: So this had started working again and now it literally just broke. Is it just me? Do i need to reinstall or something? or is the bug back?